# Multiple Queries/Mutation in Apollo 2.1

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I need some help using the new Query and Mutation component in Apollo 2.1, especially with multiple queries and mutations.

I have the following problems:

1. I have a graphql request that depends on a previous graphql result, how can I deal with this?
2. How do I add two different mutations (in my component I need to do two different actions) in a component that already has a query?

Answer (score 25):

**edit 2019/08/24**
from the Apollo [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/hooks-migration/):

> The new hooks API for Apollo Client is a simpler way to fetch data in
>   your React app without the boilerplate of render prop components and
>   higher-order components (HOC). We recommend using hooks for all new
>   Apollo code going forward.

**original answer:**
You are supposed to nest them. See this example:

```
const NumbersWithData = () => (
  <Query query={QueryOne}>
    {({ loading: loadingOne, data: { one } }) => (
      <Query query={QueryTwo}>
        {({ loading: loadingTwo, data: { two }}) => {
          if (loadingOne || loadingTwo) return <span>loading...</span>
          return <h3>{one} is less than {two}</h3>
        }}
      </Query>
    )}
  </Query>
);
```

To help with keeping the nesting manageable, you could check [react-adopt](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt). They have an Apollo ToDo App example, where they combine a Query and multiple Mutations.

Comment: @brunodahora, cool - if you feel this answered your question, pls don't forget to click on accept

Comment: I don't really like the idea of nesting. What if I've got a dashboard with 20 mutations?

Comment: Then you aren't a React dev and you should split everything up into more components

Comment: @JamieHutber strong statement, but I agree on principle. If you have one component required to perform several query/mutations, it is probably a code smell and you should break down your application into more separated components where possible.

Comment: I just re-read that, I did come on pretty heavy there... I wonder why. lol But ye, i do agree with it overall too.

Comment: The link in the first sentence is dead.  Does anyone know where this is documented?  has any of this changed since apr 2018?

Comment: @ox, I couldn't find the page either, so I removed the link.

Answer (score 10):

For this purpose `react-apollo` exports a `compose` function. Using this function you may cleanly use several component enhancers at once. Including multiple graphql(), or even Redux connect() enhancers.

```
import { Mutation, compose, graphql } from "react-apollo";

class AddTweet extends Component {
....
....
....
}
export default compose(
  graphql(GET_AUTHORS, { name: "getAuthors" }),
  graphql(ADD_TWEET, { name: "addTweet" }),
  connect(...), // incase you are using Redux
)(AddTweet);
```

An important note is that `compose()` executes the last enhancer first and works its way backwards through the list of enhancers.

One more thing lets say you were using `this.props.data` now you will get get `undefined`. just `console.log(this.props)` and you will see what is happening to props now. You will be having two properties now `getAuthors` and `addTweet`. So now it will be `this.props.name-in-compose.name-of-type-in-typeDefs` i.e. `this.props.getAuthors.getUsers`. It took me a bit to figure it out.

Comment: Where is `Mutation` used in this example can I ask?

Comment: It's very bad to use Redux with apollo.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion,

1. To make a request depends on previous request, you can break that request to children component and pass result of previous request like `props` to it and do that request.
2. To use more than one mutation and queries, you can use `compose` like this

   ```
   ...
   @compose(
    graphql(GET_FEEDS_QUERY, {name : 'getFeeds'}),
    graphql(CREATE_NEW_POST, {name: "createNewPost"}),
    graphql(LIKE_POST_MUTATION, { name: "unlikePostMutation"}),
    ...
   )
   class HomeScreen extends Component {
    ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [Medium Post](https://medium.com/@access2emma/perform-graphql-mutation-and-query-on-the-same-screen-page-b7bda587dac6) about how to combine Mutation and Query on the same Component.
Here is a snippet from the post

```
// other import
import {Query} from “Apollo-graphql”; // new Query Component
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import UserComponent from '../component/UserComponent'; // any component to display query result
const GET_ALL_USER = gql`
    {
        allUsers: {
            firstname,
            lastname,
            username,
            # other information
        }
    }
`
const UPDATE_USER_STATUS = gql`
    mutation UpdateUserStatus($userID: ID!, $status: Int!){
        updateUserState(userID: $userID, status: $status){
            firstname,
            lastname
            username
            # other information
        }
    }
`
ExampleComponent extends React.Component{
    onEditInformation = async (user) => {
        const response  = await mutate({
            variables: {userID: user}
        })
    }
render(){
        return(
            <Query query={GET_ALL_USER}>
                {({data: { allUsers }}) => {
                    return allusers.map(user => {
                        return (
                            <UserComponent
                                user={user}
                                onEdit={() => this.onEditInformation(user)}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                }}
            </Query>
        )
    }
}
export default graphql(UPDATE_USER_STATUS)(ExampleComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Asides from using `compose` from `react-apollo`, another great utility library you can check it out is [react-adopt](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt). A great small utility lib that helps you to compose **multiple** `render props` type components so you don't have a nested hell patterns.

I have wrote a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576632/2677391) that basically covers all your current needs in terms of:

- How to consume a previous result from your mapper fn via react-adopt
- Combine multiple Query/Mutations from Composed component via react-adopt

Here's the [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576632/2677391) you're looking for & hopefully can be helpful to solving your problems :)

Comment: @brunodahora, if you're still looking for `react-adopt` solution, [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903546/how-to-dynamically-set-variables-in-mutation-with-react-adopt/56576632#56576632) here :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Best solution for this

### Simply nest graphql function

`export default graphql(addBookMutation)(graphql(getAuthorsQuery)(AddBook))`

You can refer to this

[Apollo concepts](https://github.com/ipankajgarg/Getting-started-with-apollo)