# Does apollo client support transactions?

Tags: transactions, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I have a nuxtjs app that uses apollo module for graphql communication with FaunaDB.
I want to make multiple mutations in one transaction to FaunaDB. So I don't want to send a different request for every single mutation to FaunaDB, I want to make a single request that contains all the mutations. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes transactions are supported by GraphQL**

There is [a graphql guide](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#multiple-fields-in-mutations) about **Multiple fields in mutations** .

And a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782270/multiple-queries-mutation-in-apollo-2-1) answer.

*multiple mutations* is not directly related with vue-apollo, it's a feature of Apollo client.

**Answer is in GraphQL layer.**

[Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#executing-a-mutation) documantation has information about it.

[Vue-Apollo-todos](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo-todos) is a good example for mutations.

And there is a example in [apollographql issues](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/238#issuecomment-250652349)

```js
graphql(gql`
  query UserQuery ($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      # ... selection set
    }
  }

  query PostQuery($postId: ID!) {
    post(id: $postId) {
      # ... selection set
    }
  }

  mutation CreateUser ($createUserInput: CreateUserInput!) {
    createUser(data: $createUserInput) {
      # ... selection set
    }
  }

  mutation CreatePost ($createPostInput: CreatePostInput!) {
    createPost(data: $createPostInput) {
      # ... selection set
    }
  }
`, {
  props: ({ data: { loading, user, post }, createUser, createPost }) => {
    // ... do stuff with multiple operations
  }
});
```